# Combine XML files using Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I need to combine xml files using perl. I wrote this code and called from a batch script, this works but using XML writer, it works but it replaces all the < and > characters in the XMl to `&gt;` and `&lt;` I want it to just dump whatever is there in the @data array to the new XML file.

```
my $XML_COMBINE_FILE = IO::File->new("> $TARGET_DIR/output.xml");

my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => $XML_COMBINE_FILE);
$writer->startTag("wd:Report_Data" => "?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>");

foreach (@downloaded_file_list) 
{

    open FILE, "< $TARGET_DIR/$_" or die "Cannot open $_ for reading: $!\n";
    my @data = <FILE>;
    close FILE;

    $writer->characters("@data");
}

    $writer->endTag("wd:Report_Data");
    $writer->end();
    $XML_COMBINE_FILE->close();

    print "XML files Combined Successfully";
```

Any help is much appreciated ! Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried dumping the @data into a txt file or print it to see whether it's reading the < > in first place to be sure the writing is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

```
characters($data)

    Add character data to an XML document. All '<', '>', and '&' characters in the $data argument will automatically be escaped using the predefined XML entities:

raw($data)

    Print data completely unquoted and unchecked to the XML document. For example raw('<') will print a literal < character. This necessarily bypasses all well-formedness checking, and is therefore only available in unsafe mode.
```

So you could try this, it may work:

```
my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => $XML_COMBINE_FILE, UNSAFE => 1);
...
foreach (@downloaded_file_list) 
{

    local $/=undef;
    open my $fh, "<",  "$TARGET_DIR/$_" or die "Cannot open $_ for reading: $!";
    my @data = <$fh>;
    close($fh);

    $writer->raw(@data);
}
```